# Visual studio 2019 - Debugging - Datatips

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.6.
How can I see the contents of the datatable?

According to the documentation I should see a magnifying glass icon.
But it doesn't appear.

Is there a specific option in de Debugging options perhaps?

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to have a temporary DataTable variable that receives the result of the call to _returnDALDataTable_ then you should be able to see the magnifying glass icon hovering on the new variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I enabled this option and now I can see the local variables:
Options > Debugging > General > Suppress JIT optimazation on module load

[image]